# Insert into from deleted output clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am archiving my table data to archive tables. For this I am just inserting the records to the archive table based on some condition and in the next statement I delete the records with the same condition in the main table.

But to improve performance it was suggested to use a single statement with an output clause.

***Code :***

```
INSERT INTO AR_tbl1 
SELECT GETDATE(), D.*
FROM
    (DELETE FROM tbl1 
    WHERE Amt >= 40  
    OUTPUT DELETED.*) D
```

But this is not working. If I comment the where clause it works. Please help me to fix the logic with `where` clause

Comment: The order is `delete` ... `output` ... `where`. You have the clauses the wrong way round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finished. thanks Martin. The problem lies in the order. Output clause needs to add before the where clause.

***New Code :***

```
INSERT INTO AR_tbl1 
SELECT D.*
FROM
    (DELETE FROM tbl1 
    OUTPUT DELETED.* 
WHERE Amt >= 40) D
```

Comment: Don't forget the "D" as the last character!

Answer (score 9):

Although this question has an accepted answer, I think the following query would be more concise **instead of** using `derived table`.

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 
OUTPUT GETDATE(), DELETED.*
INTO AR_tbl1
WHERE Amt >= 40
```